# Solve the following equation : $\log_2(x)*\log_4(x)*\log_8(x)=4.5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have the following equation :

$$\log_2(x)*\log_4(x)*\log_8(x)=4.5$$

Usually, I do post what I made to do, but in this case a friend of mine tackle me with this question after I didn't mess with these kind of equations more than two years so I forgot how to approach these kind of equations, I'll be glad if someone could solve it so I'll learn from the solution.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: hint all logs are of form base 2^k

Comment: Hint: For any $m$, $2^m = 4^{m/2} = 8^{m/3}$. Now recall the definition of the logarithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach:
Note: $\log_a a = 1$, $\log_b a = \frac{\log_n a}{\log_n b}$

$$ \log_2 x\times \log_4 x \times \log_8 x = 4.5 = \frac{9}{2}$$

change all logs to base 2:

$$\log_2 x \times \frac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 4}\times \frac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 8} = \frac{9}{2} $$

$$ \log_2 x \times \frac{1}{2}\log_2 x \times \frac{1}{3}\log_2 x = \frac{9}{2}$$

$$(\log_2 x )^3 = 27$$

I trust you can finish it from here.

Comment: It doesn't appear clear because your base is still in the power of 2, and the answer does not have a common factor of 2 (see my answer).

Comment: @DonLarynx Both you and John get $x=8$. What's the problem?

Comment: @AlexG. I did not realize $log_2(8) = 3$.

Answer (score 4):

Use the fact that $\log_a(b)=\frac{\log_c(b)}{\log_c(a)}$.

This gives $$\log_2(x)\log_4(x)\log_8(x) = \log_2(x)\frac{\log_2(x)}{\log_2(4)}\frac{\log_2(x)}{\log_2(8)}=\frac16(\log_2(x))^3$$

So $\frac16(\log_2(x))^3=4.5$, hence $(\log_2(x))^3=27$, hence $\log_2(x)=3$, and thus $x=8$. It can be seen that $x=8$ indeed satisfies the given equation.

Comment: This is a good answer because it follows through to the solution, just as the original poster requested.

Answer (score 2):

it is $$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}\frac{\ln(x)}{2\cdot\ln(2)}\frac{\ln(x)}{3\ln(2)}=\frac{9}{2}$$ and from here we get
$$\frac{\ln(x)^3}{6\cdot (\ln(2))^3}=\frac{9}{2}$$ calculating this we obtain $$\ln(x)^3=27\cdot \ln(2)^3$$ can you proceed?

Comment: Unclear how the first step simplifies to $\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: we have $$4.5=\frac{45}{10}=\frac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the [change of base](http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm) formula to see
$$
\log_4 x = {\log_2 x\over \log_2 4} = {\log_2 x \over 2}
$$
Similarly
$$
\log_8 x = {\log_2 x\over 3}
$$

Comment: This is not really an answer, either.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_2(x)∗\log_4(x)∗\log_8(x)=4.5$$

Using the log change-of-base rule $\log_c(x) = \frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(c)}$ and setting $b = 3$, we get

$$\frac{\log_3^3(x)}{\log_3(2)*\log_3(4)*\log_3(8)} = 4.5$$

Then, using the log power rule $\log_c(a^b) = b*\log_c(a)$, we get

$$\frac{\log_3^3(x)}{\log_3^3(2)} = 27$$

proceeding to be

$$\frac{\log_3(x)}{\log_3(2)} = 3$$

But then, you just multiply by the denominator on each side to get

$$\log_3(x) = \log_3(8)$$

Answer (score 0):

This equation is equivalent to :
$$\log_{2}(x)\frac{\log_{2}(x)}{2}\frac{\log_{2}(x)}{3} = 4.5$$

Because of : $$\log_{m^{n}}(x)= \frac{\log_{m}(x)}{n}$$

Comment: This is not really an answer.

Comment: @DonLarynx I think that this is not so necessary to give him a full answer, because the last part the easiest

Answer (score 0):

Raise all the logs to the same base, by raising the argument of each log by the necessary power.

$\log_2{x}\times\log_4{x}\times\log_8{x}=4.5$

$\log_8{x^3}\times\log_8{x^{3/2}}\times\log_8{x}=4.5$

$3\times(3/2)\times\log_8{x}\times\log_8{x}\times\log_8{x}=4.5$

$(log_8{x})^3=1$

$x=8$

Comment: What rule is this?

Comment: Just using intuition to be honest but it's something like $log_{a^b}(x^b)=log_{a}(x)$.  Cube the base, cube the $x$, nothing changes.

Comment: @DonLarynx Because a log quantifies the "powers" of something in a certain base, you can apply powers to the base and the same powers to the argument and it leaves the value unchanged, e.g. $log_2(8)=log_4(64)$.

Comment: Actually the reason is due to part of my answer, the log change-of-base rule. $\log_4(64) = \frac{\log_2(64)}{\log_2(4)} = \frac{2}{2}\log_2(8)$.